# How can I embed repeated data into single JSON object

Tags: mysql, json, database, angularjs, codeigniter

How can I embed below data in JSON format in such way that, I can get only one JSON object for each hall.

As you can see I have data from two tables one is from "hall_information" that is not repeated in table because hall_name ,service_provider_id & id will be entered once by user.

But in second table that "hall_price" in which i have slot_name, slot_ending_time,  slot_starting_time, hall_type, which are repeated as user can describe his price for hall for morning, evening and full day, and for hall_type mini, mantap and bunquet. so these rows can repeat 9 times for each hall with 3 hall_types and for each hall_type 3 pricing.

So i want to combine into only one row as a query result in json format. I am using php with Codeigniter & angular.js for my project. how to embed this result of query into single json object. so that while looping using ng-repeat i can get only one hall NOT 9 halls with same name. Thanks in advance.

```
var hallinfo =
[
   {
    "hall_name":"Sai mantap","id":"12","service_provider_id":"35",
    "slot_name":"morning","slot_charge":"5000","slot_starting_time":"09:00:00","slot_ending_time":"03:00:00",
    "hall_info_id":"45","hall_type":"mantap"
   },

   {
    "hall_name":"Sai mantap","id":"12","service_provider_id":"35",
    "slot_name":"evening", "slot_charge":"10000","slot_starting_time":"05:00:00","slot_ending_time":"10:00:00",
    "hall_info_id":"45","hall_type":"mini"
   },

  {
    "hall_name":"Sai mantap","id":"12","service_provider_id":"35",
    "slot_name":"full_day","slot_charge":"15000","slot_starting_time":"09:00:00","slot_ending_time":"10:00:00",
    "hall_info_id":"45","hall_type":"bunquet"
  },

  {
    "hall_name":"Raman mantap ","id":"13","service_provider_id":"36",
    "slot_name":"morning","slot_charge":"5000","slot_starting_time":"09:00:00","slot_ending_time":"03:00:00",
    "hall_info_id":"46","hall_type":"mantap"
   },

   {
    "hall_name":"Raman mantap","id":"13","service_provider_id":"36",
    "slot_name":"evening", "slot_charge":"10000","slot_starting_time":"05:00:00","slot_ending_time":"10:00:00",
    "hall_info_id":"46","hall_type":"mini"
   },
  {
    "hall_name":"Raman mantap","id":"13","service_provider_id":"36",
    "slot_name":"full_day","slot_charge":"25000","slot_starting_time":"09:00:00","slot_ending_time":"10:00:00",
    "hall_info_id":"46","hall_type":"bunquet"
  },

];
```

here are the table schemas.

```
CREATE TABLE hall_information (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    hall_name character varying(30),
    service_provider_id REFERENCES service_provider(id);
);

CREATE TABLE hall_pricing (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    slot_name slot_type NOT NULL,
    slot_charge integer NOT NULL,
    slot_starting_time time without time zone NOT NULL,
    slot_ending_time time without time zone NOT NULL,
    hall_info_id integer REFERENCES hall_information(id),
    hall_type character varying(20)
);
```

and my query to fetch all records is

```
 public function get_hall_info(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('hall_info');
    $this->db->join('hall_pricing', 'hall_info.id = hall_pricing.hall_info_id');
    $query =$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I guess this will do my work but i dont have idea to convert my data into this below form.

```
var hallinfo =
[
       {
        "hall_name":"Sai mantap","id":"12","service_provider_id":"35",
         "slots":[
                  {
                    "slot_name":"morning","slot_charge":"5000","slot_starting_time":"09:00:00","slot_ending_time":"03:00:00",
                    "hall_info_id":"45","hall_type":"mantap"
                  },
                  {
                    "slot_name":"evening", "slot_charge":"10000","slot_starting_time":"05:00:00","slot_ending_time":"10:00:00",
                    "hall_info_id":"45","hall_type":"mini"
                  },
                  {
                    "slot_name":"full_day","slot_charge":"15000","slot_starting_time":"09:00:00","slot_ending_time":"10:00:00",
                    "hall_info_id":"45","hall_type":"bunquet"
                  }
               ]
       },
       {
        "hall_name":"Raman mantap ","id":"13","service_provider_id":"36",
         "slots":[ 
                        {
                          "slot_name":"morning","slot_charge":"5000","slot_starting_time":"09:00:00","slot_ending_time":"03:00:00",
                          "hall_info_id":"46","hall_type":"mantap"
                        },
                        {
                          "slot_name":"evening", "slot_charge":"10000","slot_starting_time":"05:00:00","slot_ending_time":"10:00:00",
                          "hall_info_id":"46","hall_type":"mini"
                        },
                        {
                         "slot_name":"full_day","slot_charge":"25000","slot_starting_time":"09:00:00","slot_ending_time":"10:00:00",
                         "hall_info_id":"46","hall_type":"bunquet"
                        }
               ]
       }                  
      ];
```

Comment: better provide your table structure of mysql and query

Comment: Actually I am using postgres. @raheelshan